# How do I link a listview element with Firebase object?

Tags: java, android, firebase, listview

In the main activity, there's a listview which shows all the objects pushed to the database using `displayAllItems()` method:

```
private void displayAllItems(){
        ListView listOfItems = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_of_items);
        FirebaseListAdapter<Item> adapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Item>(this, Item.class, R.id.list_item, FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference()) {
            @Override
            protected void populateView(View v, Item model, int position) {
                TextView type, subtype, name;
                type = v.findViewById(R.id.item_type);
                subtype = v.findViewById(R.id.item_subtype);
                name = v.findViewById(R.id.item_name);

                type.setText(model.getType());
                subtype.setText(model.getSubtype());
                name.setText(model.getName());
            }
        };
        listOfItems.setAdapter((adapter));
    }
```

The listview only shows info from 3 fields of `Item` class objects. How do I get additional information about an item by clicking on it in listview, so I can use this data in a new activity?

Comment: have you checked the answer?

Comment: to test the solution, I should populate my data to listview. The method I've put in the question is broken

Comment: Why is it broken

Comment: I've just fixed it. Going to implement your solution right now

Comment: But there's one more question: how do I change object's fields in the database?

Comment: You mean update? Then you need to use `updateChildren` method

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/215189/discussion-between---and-peter-haddad).

Comment: Thanks for the help! But can I ask you to help me with search? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62158694/search-in-firebase-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `setOnItemClickListener` to click on each item in the `listView`:

```
listOfItems.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){   
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?>adapter,View v, int position){
        Item item = (Item) adapter.getItemAtPosition(position);

        Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this, NewActivity.class);    
        intent.putExtra("type",item.getType());
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

`getItemAtPosition()` will get data associated with the specified position in the list. Then use the `getters` of your class to get the data and send it to the next activity using `intent`